# Scala - match on regex for non-empty string

Tags: regex, scala, match

In Scala - I need to validate if a given string is non-empty. Following snippet returns true. What is the issue with the regex along with match?

```scala
  def isEmpty(input: String): String = {
    val nonEmptyStringPattern = raw"""(\w+)""".r
    input match {
      case nonEmptyStringPattern => s"matched $input"
      case _ => "n/a"
    }
  }
```

However, the same regex works are expected on matches method as below.

````scala
   def isEmpty(input: String): String = {
    val nonEmptyStringPattern = raw"""(\w+)""".r
    input match {
      case input if nonEmptyStringPattern matches( input) => s"matched $input"
      case _ => "n/a" ```.  
    }
  }
````

Does this mean match cannot have regex instances ?

Comment: Why not just check the length of the string?

Comment: It is possible to use length with if-else expression. No second thoughts. But I was curious to use match with regex.

Comment: Even the following snippet. Match with pattern guards work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as `case x => ...` creates a new variable `x` to match against, it's the same for `case nonEmptyStringPattern => ...`. A new variable is created that shadows the existing `nonEmptyStringPattern`. And as it's an unencumbered variable, it will match anything and everything.

Also, you've created and compiled a regex pattern but you have to invoke it in order to pattern match against it.

```
def isEmpty(input: String): String = {
  val nonEmptyStringPattern = "\\w+".r
  input match {
    case nonEmptyStringPattern() => s"matched $input"
    case _ => "n/a"
  }
}
```

This now works, except for the fact that not all `String` characters are `\w` word characters.

```
isEmpty("")     //res0: String = n/a
isEmpty("abc")  //res1: String = matched abc
isEmpty("#$#")  //res2: String = n/a
```

Comment: Explanation "Just as case x => ... creates a new variable x to match against, it's the same for case nonEmptyStringPattern => .... A new variable is created that shadows the existing nonEmptyStringPattern. And as it's an unencumbered variable, it will match anything and everything." from @jwvh nails the answer. Took a while to understand that match creates a variable with case. However, I am yet to understand why an unencoutered variable match anything.

Comment: @jwvh: I think You need to pass `input` string here `case nonEmptyStringPattern(input) => s"matched $input"` otherwise it will always match with "n/a".

Comment: @asanand; I removed the capture group. As you can see from the test output, it will match one or more `\w` word characters.

Comment: @jwvh: Ohh I missed that. Thanks

Comment: @dexter2305; `case x =>` creates the variable `x` that is _unencumbered_, i.e. unrestricted as to the values it can hold. In other words, there is no guard (`case x if ...`) or other condition that would cause the match to fail.